# How can I get the value in an input

Tags: selenium, input

I'm writing a script in selenium and I would like to control the values return.

I tried `.getText())` and `getAttribute("Value"))`.

My code:

```
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.id("HRTABLEZQ11-0-0_0")).getAttribute("Value"));
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.id("HRTABLEZQ11-0-0_0")).getText());
```

The HTML:

```
<input id="D*ZQ11PERPAI-0-0_0" maxlength="6" readonly="true" hrprotected="true" tabindex="-1" 
    oncontextmenu="showViewerColumnsMenu('ZQ11PERPAI','JQQ111NE','0','','','Période de paie',event);return false;" 
    onchange="setValue(topWindow.getObjectFiredEvent(window,event),'JQQ111NE');" 
    onhelp="showWimHelp(this)"
    onfocus="if (topWindow.isIE) return;selCurrent(-1,0,0,'ZQ11','JQQ111NE',true,event)" 
    class="HREDIT_DATL1" 
    style="width:60px;height:18px;text-transform:uppercase;padding:0px" 
    type="TEXT">
```

I would like to have the value of the input (10 actually), that I saw on the web page.

Actually I have null.

Comment: The HTML code is:<input id="D*ZQ11PERPAI-0-0_0" maxlength="6" readonly="true" hrprotected="true" tabindex="-1" 
oncontextmenu="showViewerColumnsMenu('ZQ11PERPAI','JQQ111NE','0','','','Période de paie',event);return false;" 
onchange="setValue(topWindow.getObjectFiredEvent(window,event),'JQQ111NE');" onhelp="showWimHelp(this)"
 onfocus="if (topWindow.isIE) return;selCurrent(-1,0,0,'ZQ11','JQQ111NE',true,event)" 
 class="HREDIT_DATL1" style="width:60px;height:18px;text-transform:uppercase;padding:0px" type="TEXT">

Comment: Your input element does not have a value attribute so it should not have an actual value.  Are you sure you have provided the correct markup?  `.getAttribute("value")` should work, but it needs there to be a value specified in the DOM to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below.

```
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.id("HRTABLEZQ11-0-0_0")).getAttribute("textContent"));
```